# Rodapé ir até o final da página

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Meu rodapé tem um uma altura definida(`height: 40px;`). 
Quando o conteúdo da página em si é pequeno, a área restante depois dele fica toda em branco, por causa do background, dando uma estética ruim para o site.

Queria que depois do rodapé, ele preenche-se todo o resto da página e não fica-se branco.

Entretando quando coloco `height: 100%` em `<footer>`ele ultrapassa o final da página criando um scroll indesejado. Ou seja, aumenta o tamanho total da página em si.

A única solução que vejo é colocar `background-color: mesmacordofooter;` no `body`. Porém estou achando que isso é uma prática ruim de programação.

`footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(45,45,47);
    color: #B8BBC1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}`

`#footercontainer {
    width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
}`

`<footer>
   <div id="footercontainer"> 
   </div>
</footer>`

Comment: Coloque o `HTML` também.

Comment: @Edilson a parte principal do HTML em relação  a dúvida já está no post. Não posso enviar o HTML todo por que é muito código e fica inviável colocar aqui. Acho que o que eu já postei é o suficiente para entender o problema. Caso necessite de algo, só pedir.

Comment: Digo, que coles apenas um esboço, por exemplo as `tags` principais que compõem esse flex, para que possamos ver se o `footer` está abaixo ou acima de quem.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta, é exatamente o que eu acabei de fazer no meu código. :)

Então vamos lá:

O seu html deve ficar algo desse tipo:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <main>conteúdo do seu site</main>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

E o seu css assim:

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
min-height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper main {
flex: 1;
}
```

Dessa forma, sempre que o conteúdo do seu site for pequeno, seu footer vai ficar na parte inferior do navegador. E sempre que o conteúdo for maior do que a tela, o footer vai acompanhar o conteúdo e aparecer no final do scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Tente este código:

```
footer {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgb(45,45,47);
 height: 40px;
 display: flex;
}

#footercontainer {
    width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

<footer>
  <div id="footercontainer"> 
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Não deu muito certo. Estou trabalhando com Flex. 
Preciso dos Flexs e de #footercontainer.
Quando o conteúdo do site é grande e tem scroll, o rodapé fica por cima dele e no meio da página.

Comment: Alterei a resposta recolocando as referencias. Se o Flex é necessário, considere colocar como tag na pergunta.

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa. Parece que sempre que usa position: absolute e bottom: 0, ele fica em cima do conteúdo no meio da página, quando o conteúdo é grande. Não sabia do lance das Tags, vou usar a partir de agora.

Comment: Quando alterei o codigo, não tinha lido esta parte do alinhamento, só a do flex. Agora corrigi e sim, trata-se dos atributos `position:fixed;`, `bottom: 0;` e `right: 0;`

Comment: Ai você está usando o fixed. Ele fica fixo no fim da página e acompanha a rolagem da página sempre localizado no final dela. É uma solução razoável mas ainda não é o que eu quero.

Comment: Reparei nisso, também. Você já tem duas opções: esta que propus e a que mencionou na pergunta (colocar a cor no background). Sem conhecer os códigos, acho que outra solução genérica, vai depender de um código mais complexo (javascript) que detecte a posição do footer e o expanda.